# Why the Popup in the MarkerClusterGroup is not displayed?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

The data comes from the Server to json, after receiving it I display the Leaflet on the map. Since there are a lot of markers, I merge them into clusters using MarkerClusterGroup, clusters appear along with markers, but pop-ups on click do not display information, everything works fine without clusters. Who has done this? Need help, Google did not help

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import MapService from "../../services/map-service";
import {Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup} from "react-leaflet";
import MarkerClusterGroup from 'react-leaflet-markercluster';
import Spinner from "../../spinner";
import ErrorIndicator from "../../error-indicator";
import {ListGroup, ListGroupItem} from "react-bootstrap";
import "./geo-map.css";
import 'react-leaflet-markercluster/dist/styles.min.css';

export default class GeoMap extends Component {

   mapService = new MapService();

   state = {
    data: [],
    loading: true,
    error: false
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.updateMap();
}

onGeoDataLoaded = (data) => {
    this.setState({
        data: data,
        loading: false,
        error: false
    });
};

onError = (error) => {
    this.setState({
        error: true,
        loading: false
    })
};

updateMap() {
    this.mapService.getProjects().then(this.onGeoDataLoaded).catch(this.onError);
}

render() {

    const {data, loading, error} = this.state;

    const hasData = !(loading || error);
    const errorView = error ? <ErrorIndicator/> : null;
    const spinner = loading ? <Spinner/> : null;
    const mapView = hasData ? <MapView data={data}/> : null;

    return (
        <div className="geo-map">
            {errorView}
            {spinner}
            {mapView}
        </div>
    )
 }
}
const createMarkers = (data) => {
return data.data.map((item, index) => (
    <Marker key={item.id} position={[item.geoJson.coordinates[1], item.geoJson.coordinates[0]]}>
        <Popup maxWidth="auto">
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroupItem>
                    <strong>Наименование</strong><br/>
                    {item.name}
                </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem>
                    <strong>Дата закрытия контракта</strong><br/>
                    {item.endDate}
                </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem>
                    <strong>Заказчик</strong><br/>
                    {item.contractor}
                </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem>
                    <strong>Номер договора</strong><br/>
                    {item.contractNumber}
                </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem>
                    <strong>Путь к полевым мат.</strong><br/>
                    {item.dataPathRequest}
                </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem>
                    <strong>Путь к камер. мат.</strong><br/>
                    {item.dataPathResponse}
                </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem>
                    <strong>Путь к паспорту </strong><br/>
                    {item.passportPath}
                </ListGroupItem>
            </ListGroup>
        </Popup>
    </Marker>
))
};
const MapView = (data) => {
console.log("Data from state", data);
const markers = createMarkers(data);
return (
    <Map center={[39.90, 48.98]} zoom={4} maxZoom={22} attributionControl={true} zoomControl={true}
         doubleClickZoom={true} scrollWheelZoom={true} dragging={true} animate={true} easeLinearity={0.35}>
        <TileLayer url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'/>
        <MarkerClusterGroup>
            {
                markers
            }
        </MarkerClusterGroup>
    </Map>
)
};
```

[Popup not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr6ST.jpg)

[Popup works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiPB3.jpg)

Comment: When is it populated? Most possible data is null or undefined during fetching time and after a while  they get populated due to async action.

Comment: @kboul The data is not empty, since without clusters everything is displayed correctly. Popup not showing even with plain text in MarkerClusterGroup

Comment: But you have a second picture where popup is displayed. It would be useful if you created a codesandbox or sth similar to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @kboul On the second picture shows popups without MarkerClusterGroup. Ok, I'll do a codesandbox and write to you, thanks!

Comment: @kboul unfortunately, it was not possible to deploy the project to the codsandbox, since the backend is on the local server, there is no access from outside to it, and it was not possible to manually insert the data, many errors got out

Comment: Use a small sample static json as a backend response

Comment: @kboul https://github.com/stepanovvgeorgy/otgr-frontend - there is a link to github

Comment: @kboul https://codesandbox.io/s/otgr-geoportal-w5y9q - if i use a small sample static json then errors appear

Comment: change this line `const response = await fetch(`${this._apiBase}${url}`);` to equal to a sample local json varaible similar to your response

Comment: @kboul works, what could be the problem?

Comment: @kboul if i get data from server

Comment: Does it work eventually?

Comment: @kboul Thanks, it works, but how to implement this in the case of a server?

Comment: It should be identical process.

Comment: @kboul Thank you very much, I transferred to the local project from the codesandbox, I receive data from the server and everything is displayed correctly, but to be honest I did not understand how this happened

Comment: me neither :). As long as it works it is ok.

Comment: @kboul right:) thanks again!